# Phoenix not connected on zookeeper from Cloudera CDH5 distribution

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, cloudera-cdh, apache-phoenix

I installed zookeeper, hbase-master, hbase-regionserver in theree different systems. And configured according to the CDH5 guideline. Able to start all the services. Added Phoenix-4.2.2 on zookeeper node. When trying to connect database by `./sqlline localhost` , getting below error

`ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null`

please help

Answer (score 0):

i assume you have copied phoenix-*-server.jar to all region server hbase lib.. check what is the zookeeper quorem server name giver hbase-site.xml .. if the machine name is given then you should map machine name to its ip address in /etc/hosts..hope this helps